Traveling to the US for research under VWP/B
Good morning, I'll briefly explain my situation. I'm an Italian researcher who should go to the US (for the first time in my life) to conduct research. My stay lasts 1 month, I'm not paid by the host institution, and my research does not benefit the host institution. I will meet some colleagues to discuss research and participate in some seminars (I will probably also give a seminar). This is the research activity in which I will be involved.
I work at an Italian university (so I have my salary from my institution) and I have the right to receive reimbursement for this stay from an Italian national scientific agency not related to my university (because I won a competition for such a fellowship) after giving them the certifications of my stay from the host institution (they will prepare these certifications).
I'll pay the expenses for the flight and accommodation in advance, and when I come back to Italy, I will ask for reimbursement. Under these conditions, is the ESTA VWP-Business sufficient for my stay? What do I have to declare exactly: that I'm going to the US for independent research?
I also read somewhere on this forum that the CBP may ask how I will maintain myself. I'll answer: I pay on my own, and when I come back, I will ask for reimbursement from the Italian national agency. Could this explanation about my finances potentially conflict with or cause any issues regarding my VWP/B status?
Finally, health insurance is mandatory. Can I get it from an Italian/European insurance company, or are there any specific bureaucratic instructions to be followed?

For insurance: check in Italy about coverage on US (is US included, just for holidays or also 1 month working?), else you should do an additional insurance -- Personally I would never pay for myself and ask for refund: they should pay (but I know in Italy things go backward).

@GiacomoCatenazzi and what about the other questions? Is the period of the stay considered "working"? Isn't it in contrast with the declarations of VWP/B?

The rest: I let people to do a proper answer. In B visa some working is allowed (visiting, stages, learning, exchanges, etc.) to a US branch/parent company/related company. I see your case similar to that, but I let people with more knowledge to properly answer.

FWIW: I was in a similar situation many years ago (giving a talk at a US conference and unable to conclusively determine by Internet research alone whether this is forbidden "work" or not). My solution (recommended by the US embassy) was to get a visa, even though I would have qualified for WVP. Yes, there was some cost and bureaucracy involved, but the good thing about the visa is that the travel reason is checked for eligibility before your actual travel, greatly reducing the risk of the CBP officer having a different opinion.

@Heinzi how did you manage to get access to someone at the embassy to ask for advice?  What was the person's position -- was it in fact a consular officer from the visa service or someone else?  Which US embassy was it?  I ask because it is often unclear how to ask such questions; often all you can find on the web site is the link for creating an application and/or making an interview appointment.

@phoog: This was the US embassy in Austria. I just picked up the phone and called them. They had a separate phone number for making visa appointments, and I remember being slightly annoyed because it was a premium-rate number. However, I was able to explain my situation to the person on the phone, and he advised me to get a visa. This was more than 15 years ago, so things might have changed in the meantime.

Generally, participating in conferences, seminars, and meetings are acceptable reasons to travel under VWP/B status. The length is slightly unusual, but not entirely unheard of. Avoid saying the words "work" or "job" since they may trigger the CBP officer.
The insurance requirement is for travel insurance. Check with your insurance in Italy if they cover travel, if not you might need a dedicated travel insurance policy for this trip. This is usually purchased in your home country with the intention to take care of emergencies while you travel and cover the expenses to evacuate you back home. You should probably have at least some coverage since healthcare costs in the US for uninsured can be quite high.

So, what I have to say to the CBP officer? And what I have to write when applying to ESTA? Do I need an invitation letter from the host institution?

@TheWanderer You are meeting other researchers to exchange on (insert research topic) here. Or, as you wrote in your question "meet some colleague to discuss of research and participate at some seminar". Avoid mentioning you may be presenting one, while it is permissible if you're not paid for it opens other questions.

I won a competition for a fellowship. This fellowship consist of refunds of accomodation for a stay. Some American colleagues do research similar to mine so I decided to visit them. I'll spend a period of a month there, and I'll follow seminars and make research (=i.e. to exchange ideas with them) with the colleagues. From what I understand from the ESTA application website, I have to require WB and I need an invitation letter to do research (not funded by US), right?

For the travel insurance, specifically check with your insurance company how they cover work trips, because your activities in the US will probably count as work to an insurance company. Some companies cover work trips fully; some cover them, but exclude anything happening as the result of your work; others don’t cover anything at all if you go on a trip where you do work at any point. The latter group often have add-ons or special travel insurances especially for work-related trips.
